# Running Selenium Java Code on Server

Tags: java, selenium, jar

I have a Selenium java code which is exported into jar file. On system, jar file starts browser firefox or HtmlUnit and does some required work.

I want this code to host on domain and run on server. Would be great if someone can explain few things. I know core Java but not aware of JSP and other server side things.

What are the possible and best ways to do this? 
Can I simply execute jar with php and get output file if yes then what should be server requirement to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have downloaded selenium-server-standalone-{VERSION}. jar place it on the computer with the browser you want to test. Then from the directory with the jar run the following

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-{VERSION}.jar
```

Then create a driver object that connects to the Remote Webdriver server. This driver object can drive any operation similar ways on the remote server as you have been using driver object in your system.

```
 try{
        if ( browser.startsWith("IE"))
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());
        else if ( browser.startsWith("FF"))
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
        else if (browser.startsWith("GoogleChrome"))
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
        else
            logger.info("Bad browser name: " + browser + ". Unable to launch");

        }catch (MalformedURLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Samaitra but requirement is to run jar or code on server(i.e domains) not on computer with browser.

Comment: Sorry, if I have misinterpreted the question earlier. Since you already have the selenium java code exported into a jar, my recommendation would be to write a servlet that allows you to interact with the selenium java code. You can then host this servlet in Apache tomcat server or on a jetty server.